# Google Maps blank in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I integrated Google Maps in my Android app using the maps api but when I launch it stays blank and also showing the Google Logo(see picture).
[this is what the app shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoDpc.png)

```
In builde app gradle I have:
dependencies{
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In manifest.xml I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.vallabh.googlemapspractice.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="The Api Key which I got from google console" />
```

Comment: Check the logcat,if there is any error message or so;like invalid apikey

Comment: Have you looked at [32841721](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841721/) or [45550412](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45550412/)? Is your API key enabled and can you see any traffic hits on your Google Cloud Platform dashboard for that API?

Comment: First of all you hould follow the newest documentation ... I'm sure that when you are using gradle's *google-service plugin* there is no need for `"com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"` ... but you have to check what is really needed(how to setup)

Comment: I got rid of this problem by reinstalling Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use android studio try this, it's easy to solve problem
here android studio doing lot of steps auto.

**Create new google map activity**

- File -> New -> Google -> Google Maps Activity.

**find the google_maps_api.xml file**

**Follow TODO steps Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.**