# Google Maps is Blank / Empty

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

**EDIT 2: It works on an emulator or a real device with Android 10. It doesn't work with a real device on Android 9.**

I am developing a Kotlin application on Android Studio 4.0.1 .
I need to add a map into this application.

I followed this documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start

I generated an API key like it was indicated (I did it multiple times)
I added my SHA-1 key for debugging (Also did it several times)
I read a LOT of answers on this subject (but it didn't change anything) :

[google maps showing blank screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43010837/google-maps-showing-blank-screen)

[Google Maps not shown / blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841721/google-maps-not-shown-blank)

[Google Maps is showing a blank map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52848651/google-maps-is-showing-a-blank-map)

I used the Google Maps Activity and also tried to do one by myself. The map never showed up. In any case. I just have a sort of yellow background and the Google logo on bottom left corner of the map.

Here's my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ms.easink">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".application.main.view.MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"/>
        <activity android:name=".application.main.view.MainClientPageActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".application.main.view.MainTattooArtistActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".application.authentication.view.LoginClientSignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".application.authentication.view.LoginTattooArtistSignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".application.authentication.view.LoginSignInActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Could anyone lead me to the right direction help me please?

EDIT: MapsActivity

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps)
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        val mapFragment = supportFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        val sydney = LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)
        googleMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"))
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney))
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of google console]

[image: Maps Sdk enabled]

[image: Logcat]

Comment: Make sure you added the maps sdk key , and also enabled the v2

Comment: have you debugged your code? your manifest looks fine. Can you post your google maps class which all the map related code is written?

Comment: @takieddine What do you mean by enabling the V2 ?

Comment: @Umair Logcat doesn't show anything . When I debug it, my code goes into onMapRead() and my googleMap is not null (it is an instance of SupportMapFragment)

Comment: Check your logcat for the error that will be generated and please copy paste it here , when there is something wrong with maps sdk , it will throw an error in the logcat

Comment: @takieddine I've edited my post with the logcat screenshot :)

Comment: @Lena make sure you have enabled maps api v2 and go through these links,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371754/how-to-enable-google-maps-android-api-v2-in-developers-console

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

 I can see there are few things missing in your code, like location services, gms, FusedLocationProviderClient etc and make sure you activity extends implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener

Comment: @Umair I am going to follow your lead. Why is it not indicated like that in the documentation?

Comment: @Umair I don't know where to find Maps API V2 . When I write "google maps android api" in the section bar of console.developers.google, it only shows Maps SDK for Android (which is already enabled) and Places API

Comment: @MartinZeitler <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".application.main.view.MapsActivity" /> 

It's the layout generated by Google Maps Activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... After 48h, I found the solution.

In case it happens to anyone... I had no Wifi or any Internet connection.

Lesson learned !